# Python regex re.split using a specific word as a delimiter

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to do a .split on multiple delimiters so i'm trying to use re.split()

Other examples i've googled have shown using \b

```
text = "this and that;something.else\nand some more"
import re
items=re.split("[;|\.|\n|\b and \b]",text)
print items
```

this gives:

`['this', '', '', '', '', 'th', 't', 'somethi', 'g', 'else', '', '', '', '', 'some', 'more']`

I'm expecting it to use `" and "` as a separator and give:

`['this', 'that', 'something', 'else', 'and some more']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since you want to obtain words try to use a negative character class:

```
items = re.split(" and |[^a-zA-Z ]+",text)
```

Note: writing `[;|\.|\n|\b and \b]` has no sense. A character class is as a bag where you put disordered single characters, you can't put a word (ordered characters), you can't put an assertion as a word boundary. **Inside a character class `|` is seen as a literal and has not a special meaning**. You character class is exactly the same than `[abdn ;.|]`

Comment: Thanks. That worked perfectly. I used `items=re.split(" and |[;|\.|\n]",text)`

Comment: @zio: Happy for you, but please reread the notice about character classes.

Comment: However, `-` *does have* special meaning inside character classes, that it wouldn't have elsewhere ;)